# Bass Guitar rasgueado?

Tags: technique, bass-guitar

How does Victor Wooten do that super-fast tremolo plucking? It looks like his fingers are always curled and right on top of the strings. Is he *slapping* with 3 or 4 fingers rapidly or is he plucking with fingertips?

Comment: Probably both. And thumb up and down. And fretting hand tremolo. Incredible. Proves what happens when you practise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Victor Wooten thumb slaps and plucks lower strings on down and up strokes, as you would expect, but he uses a range of techniques with his fingers:

- plucking
- rasgueado
- slapping

A lot of his technique is aimed at rapid and precise percussive impacts.

It's worth watching the [4 YouTube videos](http://youtu.be/U-N54p2YlQg) he did on technique, but he has a wide range of training materials if you are really interested.

Comment: I reckon he uses thumb on each and every string on occasion.

Comment: +1 for the video link, which nicely answers the question! Don't think there's any technique or idea that he DOESN'T use!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after watching the videos carefully, I think the specific trick I was after is basically the same as a classical guitar tremolo, like in *Recuerdos de la Alahambra*, ie. *p-a-m-i*, but all on one string (the high G). And, of course, it's a lot fleshier than on the guitar. All *apoyando*, no nail.

So basically, you pinch the string with all three fingers *and* the thumb, and snap each one off, quickly in sequence. Or you could slap the thumb.